# Сортировка вложенных объектов

Tags: c#, linq

Есть сущность Request

```
public class Request
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string SitemapUrl { get; set; }

    public double TimeRequest { get; set; }
}
```

А так же коллекция этих сущностей

```
 List<Request> listRequests = new List<Request>();
```

После наполнения массива `listRequest` объектами Request мне необходимо провести сортировку `Request` по параметру `TimeRequest`. Делаю это таким образом:

```
 listRequests.OrderByDescending(p => p.TimeRequest).Select(t => t.TimeRequest);
```

Но сортировка не происходит. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: При должных настройках Visual Studio вам при сборке будут выдаваться сообщения о потерянном возвращенном значении, пока вы явно не укажете осознанную его потерю через `_ = listRequests.OrderByDescending(p => p.TimeRequest).Select(t => t.TimeRequest);`. Помогают в подобных ситуациях.

Comment: Возможно имеет смысл сортировать на месте, раз уж у нас список. Не обязательно пихать linq везде

Answer (score 1):

Вы результат сортировки никуда не сохраняете.

```
listRequests = listRequests.OrderByDescending(p => p.TimeRequest).ToList();
```